# Parallel SRAM with separate I/O ports

Tags: sram, logisim

I created a circuit containing RAM modules with separate input and output lines in Logisim:

[image: ram module]

I want to build this circuit from real items, but I could not find any SRAM chips that have separate I/O pins.

Does this kind of RAM chips exist, or I do have to find a way to somehow separate them?

Comment: I don't think so, but you can get FPGAs which contain embedded dual-port RAM blocks.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @pjc50, however in this project I wanted to stay away from FPGAs for now. I still have a hope that either I will find a separate IO bus or my circuit can be somehow modified to be suitable for bidirectional bus

Comment: Ah, you don't require bidirectional access from both ports but you just want to separate read/write? What you need is a bus arbitrator with wait states, by the sound of it. It would help to have more context.

Comment: RamIn is connected with a series of flip-flops, and RamOut is connected to a logic circuits build of CMOS gates.

Comment: What about address generation - is there only one address source circuit that applies to both "out" and "in"?

Comment: Yes, Address is connected as well as RAMIn to a series of flip flops

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38429/discussion-between-pjc50-and-disa).

Comment: While probably more than you need, a dual port RAM sold as a distinct IC, with the two ports' address inputs wired together would come quite close to literally fulfilling your requirement.

Comment: @ChrisStratton quite interesting sollution +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you describe, what you want is a tristate buffer from the 'in' side to a normal RAM databus, where the tristate has its output enable connected to the write enable signal.

(I'd include a circuit diagram, but Circuitlab doesn't have tristate buffers!)

Answer (score 3):

RAM with separate I/O certainly does exist, but is not readily available. Back 20 years ago, Cypress Semiconductor produced various RAMs with separate I/O. The closest match to your symbol was the CY7C122 and CY7C123, both 256 x 4 with separate inputs and outputs, although they also made considerably bigger parts as well. The 122 was rated at 15 - 25 nsec, while the 123 was good for 7 - 10 nsec. Power for the 122 was 330 to 495 mW, while the faster 123 was 660 to 825 mW. [Here](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/cypress/1989_CMOS_BiCMOS_Data_Book.pdf) is an archived catalog from 1996 which has the parts' data sheets.

The problem with separate I/O RAM, of course, is pinout and package size. For the same size memory, an 8-bit wide RAM will require an extra 8 pins if it uses separate I/O.

As for availability, Cypress discontinued their line long ago. However, if you want to take your chances, the CY7C122 is available from China on eBay quite cheaply.

Comment: I suspected that the constant need of minimizing packages for IC was the reason that the chips with separate IO lines were not common. Thank you for finding those old RAMs that suits my needs, +1 for that, however I think I will go for tristate buffer option.

Answer (score 0):

Ben Eater’s 8-bit CPU uses a 16 x 8-bit RAM for its memory.  He used four 74LS189 4 x 4-bit ICs.  These have separate data-in and data-out pins, but the outputs are inverted.  You can replace them with 74LS219 ICs—-identical but with non-inverted outputs.

You can find these on eBay.

This is obviously not an option if you’re looking for Kbytes or Mbytes of SRAM.  In that case you’ll need to look for more common SRAM chips with bidirectional data pins.  They’re readily available everywhere.